# Change resource of Injection in tests

Tags: java, dependency-injection, cdi

I've a producer class which produces connections from a DataSource and disposes the connection after usage.

The DataSource is injected from JNDI this way in my producer class:

```
@Resource(name = "jdbc/AAADS")
private DataSource myDS;
```

What I want is to inject a DataSource in junit tests which obviously cannot come from a JNDI service. I'm using CDI-Unit to get injections working in tests.

I Usually use commons-dbcp to create test local datasources. I think that I could create datasources and inject them in a @Resource annotated attribute but I don't know how. Can I solve this in a simple way?

Comment: a bit off-topic but just out of curiosity, why do you need an actual datasource for unit tests? shouldn't you mock external resources?

Comment: I could but in this test specifically I want to test integration with database... There are some complex queries that I would like to make sure is correct...

Comment: The typical pattern is to use a qualifier and CDI injection, rather than resource injection.  In your test, you would exclude the producer used by your main app, and replace it with a test version of it.